# Regex: differentiate 'name' and 'name_local'

Tags: php, regex

How to make regex select strictly

`'name'` : if searching for 'name',

`'name_local'` : if searching for 'name_local',

but not to select both if searching for 'name'?

Tried 
`'/('.$key.')(?!_)/'`, but it still selects both `'name'` and `'name_local'` if the `$key` is `name`.

Comment: use end of regex line. because name and name_ will match in your regex and you will get both result

Comment: There must be something else that's wrong, because with the negative look-ahead, it **doesn't** match `name_local` - [see this at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BNR9X9/1).

Answer (score 3):

You need word boundary anchor `\b`:

```
'/(\b'.$key.'\b)/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Word boundaries don't guarantee matching right piece of input string if for example the very next character isn't a word character e.g. `name-local`. Use lookarounds:

```
(?<!\S)name(?!\S)
```

PHP:

```
$re = "/(?<!\S)$key(?!\S)/";
```